# Compiler can't find DPI related functions

Tags: c++, windows, function, compiler-errors

I included all the needed headers (windows.h, winuser.h), but the compiler keeps complaining about "GetDpiForWindow" or "AdjustWindowRectExForDpi" not being defined.

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int dpi = GetDpiForWindow(GetConsoleWindow());

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> error: 'GetDpiForWindow' was not declared in this scope; did you mean
> 'GetTopWindow'?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Visual Studio?  Which version?   Please show a [mcve] that includes a code sample and the error output.

Comment: I'm using the gcc compiler included in MSYS2

Comment: Still need that [mcve]

Comment: What value does your compiler/environment give to the `WINVER` macro? If that is less than `0x0605` then those two (among other) functions aren't part of the API. From the docs: *Minimum supported client ... Windows 10, version 1607 [desktop apps only]*

Comment: I get 601. How can I solve this problem? Do I have to update windows headers?

Comment: I guess you'll need to update your Windows SDK (at least).

Comment: You _might_ be able to add `#define WINVER 0x0605` before you include `windows.h`.

Comment: I downloaded the latest Windows SDK version, and I have two problems: 
1. How can I exclude the old path for windows.h?
2. I included the new windows.h with the full path and WINVER is still 601

Comment: [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers).

Comment: I followed the guide, downloaded the latest SDK and defined those macros, but still the compiler can't find "GetDpiForWindow()"

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `#define WINVER 0x0605` before you `#include <windows.h>`. This is good idea.